# preg_replace an part of text start and end with PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find a way to replace an text like this :

```
text here ABC -some text here- CED text here
```

to

```
text here ABC -replaced text- CED text here
```

or -----------------------------------

```
text here ABC - some description here- CED text here
```

to

```
text here ABC - replaced text- CED text here
```

it mean that, we will start an part of text that begin with "ABC" and end with "CED", replace all text in between them with "replaced text".
How can I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: `preg_replace('/ABC(.*?)CED/', 'ABC - new - CED', $string);` like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$myText = 'text here ABC -some text here- CED text here';
$myText = preg_replace('/ABC(.+)CED/', 'ABC - replaced text - CED', $myText);
echo $myText;
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/izkzKcAT)

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked for me, Can I ask you one more question?
If my text like this
"text here ABC -some text here- 
CED text here"
it mean that, it has an break line before CED, how can I handle it?

Comment: You add the `s` flag to the end of the pattern. The new pattern should be `/ABC(.+)CED/s` ([example](http://codepad.org/1bazBxTR)) this will tell preg_replace that `.` means all characters **including** `\n` which is new line

Comment: Keep in mind you may want to add `?` for a non greedy match here.

Answer (score 6):

To replace what is between `ABC` and `CED` you can use a **Positive Lookbehind** and **Positive Lookahead** to retain both *ABC* and *CED* and just replace it with what you want. If the text between also includes line breaks, you can use the `s` modifier to force the dot `.` to also match newline characters.

```
$str = 'text here ABC -some text here- 
CED text here';

$str = preg_replace('/(?<=ABC).*?(?=CED)/si', ' foo ', $str);
echo $str;
```

See [`Working demo`](https://eval.in/80635)

Regular expression:

```
(?<=           look behind to see if there is:
 ABC           'ABC'
)              end of look-behind
 .*?           any character except \n (0 or more times)
 (?=           look ahead to see if there is:
  CED          'CED'
 )             end of look-ahead
```